# Returning values on click of a button

Tags: c#

I have a method as follows:

```
 private List<ProjectFile> PopUpModifiedFiles(List<ProjectFile> ModifiedFiles)
    {
        this.lblModifiedFilesMessage.Text = "Below files are modified in the Source Server and will be archived with latest version. Please select any files if they are to be retained with older version in archive";
        DataTable dtModifiedFiles = new DataTable();
        dtModifiedFiles.Columns.Add("FileName");
        foreach (ProjectFile modifiedFile in ModifiedFiles)
        {
            DataRow drFileName = dtModifiedFiles.NewRow();
            drFileName["FileName"] = modifiedFile.FileName;
            dtModifiedFiles.Rows.Add(drFileName);
        }
        gvPopUpModifiedFiles.DataSource = dtModifiedFiles;
        gvPopUpModifiedFiles.DataBind();
        this.JsContent = string.Format("setPopupPosition('{0}');setPopupBackgroundPosition('{1}');", this.divPopUpFiles.ClientID, this.divPopUpBackGround.ClientID);
        this.PopUpPanel.Visible = true;
        this.divPopUpBackGround.Visible=true;
        this.divPopUpFiles.Visible = true;
        this.lblModifiedFilesMessage.Visible = true;
        this.gvPopUpModifiedFiles.Visible = true;
        List<ProjectFile> archiveFiles = new List<ProjectFile>();
        return archiveFiles;
    }
```

This Method show a pop-up in which I have a grid view and a button.
On click of that button I have to return the  files.
My button click event is like this:

```
 protected void btnOk_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        PopUpPanel.Visible = false;
        ProjectFile filesToArchive;
        List<ProjectFile> filesToArchiveAfterUserSelection = new List<ProjectFile>();
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvPopUpModifiedFiles.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkFileSelect");
            if (chk != null & chk.Checked)
            {
                filesToArchive = new ProjectFile();
                filesToArchive.FileName = gvrow.Cells[1].Text;
                filesToArchiveAfterUserSelection.Add(filesToArchive);
            }
        }
}
```

How can I return the values on click of the button to my method?
One more thing that I am facing in this is pop-up is not visible after calling the method Pop-Up method Files. It is coming after the execution of entire code. I called this Pop-Up some where. This Pop-Up is not visible.

Comment: you can change filesToArchiveAfterUserSelection as a class field

Answer (score 0):

PHenix_yu says right.

U can put "List filesToArchiveAfterUserSelection = new List();" out of this button event and in this class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the return value after close your pop-up window,you can define a class like the below:

```
public class FileStore
{
public static List<ProjectFile> filesToArchiveAfterUserSelection = new List<ProjectFile>();
}
```

If you only want to get the return value when pop-up window open,you can change filesToArchiveAfterUserSelection as a class member in your pop-up window class